# Postgres.app not looking in the right place for extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I just installed [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/documentation) for mac to use with local rails development. Installation was pretty smooth and I got it working in an existing rails app, was able to run migrations, etc.

The problem is that when I try to install the unaccent extension, I get the following error message:

> could not open extension control file "/Users/Alex/Downloads/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/extension/unaccent.control": No such file or directory

The Postgres.app file **is not** stored in ~/Downloads anymore. I moved it to a more sensible location in /Applications. I can see that the unaccent.control file exists in /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/share/extension/ but for some reason Postgres is still looking in the old location.

The same error occurs if I just run psql from the command line and try

```
create extension unaccent
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I couldn't find anything in the Postgres.app documentation, but it may be a problem that applies to postgres installations in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be willing to bet that when you ran Postgres.app, it created a preference file which recorded the location of the application, and thus, the subfolders as well.

Look in ~/Library/Preferences for a Postgres preference file.

Comment: Thanks so much! There were three files related to postgres in the ~/Library/Preferences folder. I deleted them all and did a clean re-install, this time making sure I put the Postgres.app file in /Applications before opening it. It seems to have fixed the problem.

I wish they would have mentioned the preference files in the documentation though. http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_21